# kubernetes error syncing pod - how to debug

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I often get errors about pods not syncing / ImagePullBackOff errors on my Kubernetes cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine.  But I'm not sure how to debug the issue as I can't establish the root cause.

In the Google dashboard I can see the ReplicaSet has the warning:
Pod errors: ImagePullBackOff

If I drill down to the pod, I can see in the logs:
Message: Error syncing pod
Reason: FailedSync

[image]

but nothing further.  Why would a pod fail to sync?

UPDATE: further down in the logs I see:

```
Failed to pull image "cockroachdb/cockroach:v1.1.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: open /usr/share/zoneinfo/right/America/Pangnirtung: no space left on device
```

I've allocated cockroachdb 1 GB of persistent storage - going to try to increase to 10 GB to see if that fixes anything.  Or do I need to increase the disk size on the node pools?

Comment: k8s noob question - how did you get those logs?

Answer (score 4):

ImagePullBackOff occurs most of the time due to typos in the image name or not being able to reach the repository:

- Check for typos by copy/pasting the image name in a docker pull command (copy/paste so that any error is also copy/pasted: You want to find the error and not confirm your own bias).
- Check for reachability of DNS by logging into a pod and executing a nslookup/dig command (or ping opr anything which hits the DNS).

Comment: thanks Norbert.  This is happening with a pre-made helm image for cocroachdb I installed via Helm, so I don't think it's an issue with the name or repository.  I've attached an image of the error from my logs.

Comment: You seem to have found a 3rd possible cause: Check the disk on which the image is downloaded. You seem to have a full disk.

Comment: Happened to me, turned out I was trying to pull a private image .. derp.